# Finding the tangent planes to a torus parallel to $3x+4y-5z=20$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I've been tasked with finding all the points on the torus $S$ given by
$$
\left(6-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2+z^2=2
$$
at which the tangent plane is parallel to the plane $P$ given by $3x+4y-5z=20$ (which is, itself, tangential to $S$ at $(3,4,1)$). The method that I have employed gives me another point, but since $S$ is a torus, and $P$ is not parallel to any of $x=0$, $y=0$ or $z=0$, I know there must be at least two more.

The method that I have employed is as follows. Let $f(x,y,z)=\left(6-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2+z^2$, then we know that a vector normal to $S$ at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is given by $\nabla f(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. We use this fact, in conjunction with the fact that for two planes to be parallel, their normal vectors must also be parallel, to arrive at the condition
$$
\nabla f(x_0,y_0,z_0)=\lambda\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\\-5\end{pmatrix}
$$
for some scalar, $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. We compare the components of these vectors to obtain expressions for $z$ and $x$ in terms of $y$, and then substitute these expressions into the equation for $S$ to find that $y=4$ or $y=28/5$. Since we already have a point at which $y=4$, we discard this value, and hence we have that another tangent to $S$ which is parallel to $P$ is given by $5x/5+8y/5-2z=16$. Graphically, these are the two tangent planes in question
[image]

However, as we can see, there is an entire other half of the torus, one which I'm confident has two more points at which the tangent planes are parallel to $P$. How come I have missed these points? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How can a point be parallel to a plane? Does the question mean finding points on the torus whose tangent plane is parallel to the given plane?

Comment: @P.Lawrence My bad, I've just corrected that mistake.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be $y=\pm4, y=\pm 28.5$?

Comment: @Tony, you can also see that given the symmetry of the torus centered at the origin....  you beat me by like 10 seconds with your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note that the planes parallel to $3x+4y-5z=20$ are all of the form $3x+4y-5z=k$ for some $k$.*

The gradient is
$$
(-\frac { 2(6-\sqrt {x^2+y^2})x}{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}},-\frac {2 (6-\sqrt {x^2+y^2})y}{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}},2z).
$$

You are looking for points in the torus where the gradient is a scalar multiple of $(3,4,-5)$. This gives you four equations (three from the gradient and one from the torus):

\begin{align}
z&=-5\lambda\\
(6-\sqrt {x^2+y^2})x&=-3\lambda\sqrt {x^2+y^2} \\ 
(6-\sqrt {x^2+y^2})y&=-4\lambda\sqrt {x^2+y^2}\\
(6-\sqrt {x^2+y^2})^2+z^2&=2  . 
\end{align}
Dividing the second by the third you get 
$$
\frac{x}{y}=\frac34,
$$
so $y=4x/3$. Then 
$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{16x^2}{9}}=\frac{5|x|}{3}.
$$
So now the system is 
\begin{align}
z&=-5\lambda\\
(6-\frac{5|x|}{3})x&=-5\lambda{|x|} \\ 
(6-\frac{5|x|}{3})^2+z^2&=2  . 
\end{align}
From the first and second equation you now get

$$
z=- {5\lambda} =5\,\frac{(6-\frac{5|x|}{3})x}{{5|x|}{}}=\frac{(6-\frac{5|x|}{3})x}{{|x|}{}}.
$$
Now the last equation is 
$$
(6-\frac{5|x|}{3})^2+\left(\frac{(6-\frac{5|x|}{3})x}{{|x|}{}}\right)^2=2,
$$
so
$$
2(6-\frac{5|x|}{3})^2=2.
$$
This gives
$$
x=\pm\frac{18\pm3}5,\ \ \ 
y=\frac{4x}3=\pm\frac{24\pm4}5,\ \ \ z=\pm1.$$

So you get

- $(\tfrac{21}5,\tfrac{28}5,-1)$ and the plane is $3x+4y-5z=40$
- $(3,4,1)$ and the plane is $3x+4y-5z=20$
- $(-\tfrac{21}5,-\tfrac{28}5,1)$ and the plane is $3x+4y-5z=-40$
- $(-3,-4,-1)$ and the plane is $3x+4y-5z=-20$